# Wrong length (or \parbox)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lengths, parbox

Let's say I want a perfect alignment of these two equations (an OCD I have). The red line is just for comparison:

[image]

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newlength {\mylenght}
\settowidth{\mylenght}{$\lvert f(x) \rvert$}
\[\lim_{x \to a} \lvert f(x) \rvert = 0\]
\[\lim_{x \to a} \parbox{\mylenght}{\centering$f(x)$} = 0\]
\[\lim_{x \to a} \phantom{\lvert} f(x) \phantom{\rvert} = 0\] % edit

\end{document}
```

What is going wrong here?

Of course, I know I can do the same with `array`, `align`, etc. But I would like to do it this way, if possible (the actual expressions involved are a bit more complex).

**Edit:** I get the same result with a `\phantom`.

Comment: I was just wondering, why you want to do this way?

Comment: @mala97. Well in part just out of curiosity, and in part because both f(x) and |f(x)| appear more times in the line. This way I only need to compute the length one time.

Comment: I suppose changing `\parbox{\mylenght}{\centering$f(x)$}` to `\mathopen{}\parbox{\mylenght}{\centering$f(x)$}` will also get the job done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\lvert` and `\rvert` have status "math-open" and "math-close", respectively. You may therefore achieve your formatting objective by employing well-placed `\mathopen`, `\mathclose`, and `\hphantom{|}` directives:

[image]

PS I'm using an `align*` environment mainly to simplify aligning the `=` symbols, as I am assuming that this is also one of your formatting objectives.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'align*' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to a} \lvert f(x) \rvert &= 0 \\
\lim_{x \to a} \mathopen{\hphantom{|}}f(x)\mathclose{\hphantom{|}} &= 0 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was very simple!!!

Answer (score 4):

TeX doesn't add spaces between an **Op** and an **Open** atom, but it inserts a thin space between an **Op** and an **Ord** atom.

The **Op** here is `\lim_{x\to a}`, the **Open** is `\lvert` and `\phantom{\lvert}` is an **Ord**. You can fix by adding a negative thin space.

The `\phantom` after “f(x)” is not a problem, because TeX adds no space between a **Close** atom (here `)`) and either another close (here `\lvert`) or an **Ord** (the phantom); similarly between **Close** or **Ord** and **Rel**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\lim_{x \to a} \lvert f(x) \rvert = 0\]
\[\lim_{x \to a} \phantom{\!\lvert} f(x) \phantom{\rvert} = 0\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course one should never use two consecutive `displaymath` environments, but I guess you have text in between. In this case, forcing an alignment doesn't seem necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We have therefore proved that
\[\lim_{x \to a} \lvert f(x) \rvert = 0\]
and therefore, using standard theorems, we can conclude that
\[\lim_{x \to a} \phantom{\!\lvert} f(x) \phantom{\rvert} = 0\]
as was to be proved.

We have therefore proved that
\[\lim_{x \to a} \lvert f(x) \rvert = 0\]
and therefore, using standard theorems, we can conclude that
\[\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0\]
as was to be proved.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second format is much better, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, very simple too! And by the way, the limits are in and `itemimze` environment: ` `\item $\displaystyle\lim...`. I didn't like the alignment very much but now it's better.

Answer (score 1):

Another way. This will keep is simple and it looks nice.

If you are using `alignat` you need to specific a number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\lim_{x\to a} \lvert & (f) \rvert &&= 0 \\
\lim_{x\to a}        & (f)        &&= 0
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `&{}={}&` could be written more succinctly as `&&=`.

Comment: Thanks, now my answers have just been edited